# Are there any transparent enclosures or housing options out there for the Stellaris LaunchPad?

Tags: enclosure, launchpad, stellaris

I come from an Arduino background, where there are a number of enclosures available for the standard board sizes.
We've just installed some software on a Stellaris LaunchPad at work, and we want to show it off so people can see the RGB LED, but the board not only lacks any mounting holes, but googling doesn't seem to show up any options for enclosures either.

Do such things exist for the Stellaris LaunchPad, or is it only intended as a learning aid for hacking around with, and never for actual use?

The dimensions are listed as 5.0 cm x 5.715 cm x 10.795 mm (L x W x H)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small cottage industry appears to have sprung up in my city, for making a neat little enclosure for all 3 TI launchpads, using several layers of laser-cut acrylic sheets.

The top and bottom layers are flat clear and smoky acrylic pieces respectively, slightly wider than a credit card.

The middle layers are just the outer frame matching the top and bottom slices, with a horizontal slot inside, along the sides, for sliding the Stellaris Launchpad in, and slots cut out at left and top for the USB ports.

The enclosure can be made taller or shorter by buying additional "frame" layers, depending on what is to be plugged into the pin headers.

While this doesn't solve your specific problem it might be worthwhile seeking out your friendly neighborhood laser cutter to make you a few such "boxes". They work out pretty inexpensive.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen one.   I intend to make a case using a 3-D printer, but it won't be transparent.

There are no mounting holes because the board is intended to be attached to a larger PCB using the headers.  The larger PCB would have mounting holes.  If you don't have a larger PCB, then you can always use double-sided foam tape.